# Where to pour oil into the engine (BMW E34)?

Tags: engine, bmw, oil-change

As the title says. Also, how to open the access point (if it non trivial). (It's an M50B25TU engine)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This be what the internet gives me. I have never owned a BMW but I hope this helps. In the picture look for the red arrow and on your car look on the left rear side of the engine.
[image]